# Copy selected row from datagrid at the end of datagrid

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a datagrid and need a button that duplicates the active row and copies it into a new line. Since i am very new with vb.net i need help with it. 
I am trying it with the following code:

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles      ToolStripButton1.Click
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=TRUE")
    Dim insert_cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("dbo.Table_Insert", conn)
    insert_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    With Table1_SelectDataGridView.CurrentRow
        insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", .Cells("Name").Value)
        insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", .Cells("Age").Value)
    End With
        conn.Close()

End Sub
```

combind with the stored procedure

```
STORED PROCEDURE [dbo].[Table_Insert]
         @Name varchar(20)
         @FeierT_ID int
AS 
BEGIN 
 SET NOCOUNT ON 

 INSERT INTO dbo.table1
      ( 
        Name,
        Age    
      ) 
 VALUES 
      ( 
        @Name,
        @Age
        ) 
END
```

When i try to run it in visual studio i get the error: 'Column "Name" cannot be found.' Even thou the table column name is "Name" and "Age" btw. "Age" cannnot be found too. Maybe this is the wrong approach at all. Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sqlcommand you set "dbo.Table_Insert" and your stored procedure name is "dbo.Table1_Insert". Problem is not here?...

Comment: Hi Chris. No that was just a mistake i made while substituting projectspecific names for a better reading here. I change that in the code above now.

Comment: When you write "column Name cannot be found" the error happens in DataGridView or when executing the stored procedure? how do you populate DatagridView and create columns?

Comment: I used the debugger and the error happens when it tries to execute the line "insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", .Cells("Name").Value)". How i populate the DatagridView: I created a new Element -> dataset and dropped the dataadapter into the form. I assigned the stored procedures (Select, Update, Insert and Delete) in the wizard.

Comment: Did you try to get the cell value from column index instead of its name?

Comment: switching to index gives me the following error msg: “Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index”

Comment: @ruedi Strange... I asked you to try with column index because I was suspecting a "case sensitive issue". But if you can't access dgv cell value with column index, I really don't see what is wrong. Just to be sure, you know that column index is 0 based index? Note that if you pass this issue, I am not sure that your code will work because you also  need to call insert_cmd.executeNonQuery

Comment: i took some columns out in the dgv but then i havent had access to this columns, that was the problem. i added the columns and set them to invisible so i could access them and it works. @Chris: Thank you very much for your help!!! I am comming from vba and started the index at 1, i read that 1000 times and still made that mistake. hmmm....

Answer (score 0):

For Datagridview Databound you have to commit additional record to datasource (table)

So, you have to do

```
"INSERT INTO mytable ( fields here ... ) VALUES ( values here ..)"
```

then to refresh your datagridview ..

```
dt2.datasource = mytable
```

**ADDED :**

For your code ... try change like this

```
insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", .item("Name"))
insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", .item("Age"))
```

Comment: first off: Thanks! i tried to implement what you suggested. could you please have a look at my first post, i modified it.

Comment: unfortunately 'CurrentRow' doesnt know 'item'.